# Method in Vue3/Vite

Tags: function, vue.js, methods, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Can somebody tell me please how to implement my "del" method in Vite?
With my actual code I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler
> at <Home onVnodeUnmounted=fn ref=Ref< Proxy {…} > >
> at     at  warn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38
> logError @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:212 handleError @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:204 callWithErrorHandling @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158 callWithAsyncErrorHandling @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164 invoker @
> runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:349 runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:218
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined

These are the relevant parts from my code:

```
<template>
<div>
<h1>Alle Aufgaben</h1>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(task, index) in tasks" :class="{ 'done' : task.finish}">
                <p>{{task.description}}</p>
                <button class="doneChange" @click="doneChange(index)">✓</button>
                <button class="del" @click="del(index)">X</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, reactive, computed } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    let tasks = [
            {description: "Frühstücken", finish: true},
            {description: "Lernen", finish: false},
            {description: "Trainieren", finish: false},
            {description: "Einkaufen", finish: false},
            {description: "Mails", finish: false},
            {description: "Abendessen", finish: false},
        ];

    const del = (index) => this.tasks.splice(index,1);

        return { tasks, del };
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tasks should be defined as ref property and mutated using `value` field :

```
<script>
import { ref, reactive, computed } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    let tasks = ref([
            {description: "Frühstücken", finish: true},
            {description: "Lernen", finish: false},
            {description: "Trainieren", finish: false},
            {description: "Einkaufen", finish: false},
            {description: "Mails", finish: false},
            {description: "Abendessen", finish: false},
        ]);

    const del = (index) => tasks.value.splice(index,1);

        return { tasks, del };
    }
};
</script>
```

`this` is not accessible in the setup hook